# In-memory nosql database that can do upto a million reads

Tags: arm, in-memory-database, nosql

I have been looking up for databases that can do up to a million writes per second which should also be an in-memory , nosql database which will run on an arm based architecture.

I have read about aerospike but it does not support arm based architectures.

Can somebody suggest a database for the above requirements. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis makes some claims to extraordinary performance, and at least some have had success building it for ARM.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/4j_ohRJTD5g

Answer (score 1):

Aerospike has a unique hybrid memory architecture where you can decide how you want to split the data between in-memory & storage.
Link: https://aerospike.com/products/features/hybrid-memory-architecture/

Let me know if you need any help related to Aerospike at any point in time.